# How to reload browser from code in Odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, browser-refresh

I created a button(Edit) in sale order line and when i am using this button then values returns in sale order form.  Process is going well, but problem is that changes reflected after browser reload( Either F5 or UI). And i want this browser reload by coding. So, What kind of syntax or method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reload` tag:

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'reload',
}
```